# How to keep menu in collapse and expanded state after page reload using jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies, sidebar

I want to keep my sidebar collapse or expanded while page refresh as per the users choice., I have three files.
Header.php
Sidebar.php

Header contains the button only to click to expand collapse sidebar and sidebar contains the html of sidepanel.

I want to show the collapse and expand works with cookie if users selected expanded the sidebar it should always show expanded sidebar while page refresh, either shows collapse it should show collapse sidebar.

It works with body class "mmc", I want to add body class mmc while users selected the collapse and it will never expire till users not selected the other option, even while users refresh the page.

**Jquery**

//use for sidebar menu

```
$("#main-menu-toggle").on("click", function (event){
           event.preventDefault(); 

    $("body").toggleClass("mmc");
    alert('root');


    if($('body').hasClass('ccm')){
        localStorage.setItem('mmc', 'ccm');
         localStorage.removeItem('ccm');
    }
    else if (!$('body').hasClass('ccm')){
        localStorage.removeItem('mmc');
        localStorage.setItem('ccm', 'mmc');
    }



    //$.cookie('main-menu-toggle', true);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body class="ccm">
<button id="main-menu-toggle" type="button"><i class="navbar-icon fa fa-bars icon"></i><span class="hide-menu-text">HIDE MENU</span></button>

<div id="main-menu"  class="sminscroll">
        <p class="navtxt hide">NAVIGATION</p>
          <ul class="navigation">
            <li class="mm-dropdown mm-dropdown-root"><a href="Javascript:void(0);"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-cubes"></i> <span>Group Management</span></a>
              <ul >
                <li class="mmc-title">Group Management</li>
                <li><a href="group-management.php"><span class="dash"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></span>View Group</a></li>
                <li><a href="create-groups.php"><span class="dash"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></span>Create Group</a></li>
                <li class="hide"><a href="edit-group.php"><span class="dash"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></span>Edit Group</a></li>

                <li class="hide"><a href="group-details.php"><span class="dash"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></span>Group Details</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
<ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are setting 3 different `click` event handlers to your `#main-menu-toggle` button. Have you tried to debug their sequence? And generally I'm trying to understand what is the purpose of such kind of approach?

Comment: Actually i want to expand collapse state maintain while page refresh and also the expand and collapse work with the resize the window, load the window and on toggle the button.

Comment: I just wanted to maintain the state of toggle to add remove class and it save in local storage.